# Ускорение обработки itertools.permutations()

Tags: python, python-3.x, производительность, memory

```
    need = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), input().split()))
    mess = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), input().split()))
    for i in range(len(mess)):
        for j in list(itertools.permutations(mess[i])):
            if("".join(j) in need and "".join(j) != mess[i]):
                mess[i] = ('#' * len(mess[i]))
                break
    print(" ".join(mess))
```

Как можно уменьшить объем памяти для программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `itertools.permutations` генерирует итератор по всем перестановкам. Это означает, что все комбинации не вычисляются сразу, а лишь задаётся правило их вычисления.

Когда вы пишите

```
list(itertools.permutations(mess[i]))
```

происходит вычисление всех перестановок и создание из них списка, что забивает память. Итератор позволяет проходит по нему в цикле, вычисляя каждую итерацию следующее значение и забывая старое. Поэтому нужно писать так:

```
for j in itertools.permutations(mess[i]):
```

Например, такой [код](https://ideone.com/GSC1DW)

```
import itertools, sys
a = itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # 184
print(sys.getsizeof(list(a)))  # 5888
```

показывает, какая большая разница в потреблении памяти между этими записями.